# Optimizing multiple Active Record queries in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm unfamiliar with Ruby and trying to figure out how best to use ActiveRecord. Currently, I have a problem where I get an ID from one object, and then want to use that ID to search for another object and get it's values and map them to a new object, like so:

```
Obj_features = {}
ObjFeature.where(obj_id: @obj.id).map{|ft| obj_features[ft.feature_id] = Feature.where(id: ft.feature_id).select('id, title, icon')}
@features = obj_features.values()
```

I'm fairly certain that second line isn't the best way to do this, but I can't figure out how to change it.

Comment: Are you looking for associations (possibly using includes)?

Comment: I think I was looking for associations. I figured it out with some help on IRC; I needed :has_many and through: to be set in the Model.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :object_feature
end

class ObjectFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :features
end


obj_feature.find(objid).feature = feature.find(feature_id)
```

you should also take a look at the rails  [Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Thanks. Close: It turns out I needed this set in my Park model:   
has_many :features, through: :park_features